# FFmpeg: image intro

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to add an image intro to a video for about 5 seconds but the time could be variable.
I made a 5 seconds during intro.mkv with the following command:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i png.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 out.mp4`

The problem is that cmd doesn't know the following command which is exactly what I need. This command is copy pasted from the FAQ of FFmpeg.

`ffmpeg -i opening.mkv -i episode.mkv -i ending.mkv -filter_complex \
  "[0:0] [0:1] [0:2] [1:0] [1:1] [1:2] [2:0] [2:1] [2:2]
   concat=n=3:v=1:a=2 [v] [a1] [a2]" \
  -map '[v]' -map '[a1]' -map '[a2]' output.mkv`

The error is: (2> output.txt isnt working for some reason)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This will overlay your png intro image over a 25 frames/second video for 5 seconds, followed by a 1-second fade into your video:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 5 -i in.mp4 -r 25 -loop 1 -i intro.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:125:25:alpha=1 [intro]; [0:v][intro] overlay [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -acodec copy out.mp4
```

If your video is not 25 fps, change the `-r` value and the numbers after the `fade` (e.g. multiply by 30/25 if your video is 30 fps).  To change the duration of the intro change the `-itsoffset` and the first number after the `fade`.  If you want it show the image with audio from the beginning of the video (in place of the first few seconds of video) then you can reduce or eliminate the `-itsoffset`, which is the amount of time that it will shift the video forward to make room for the intro.

Of course you can use any supported video format for your input and output files, and can add any other video encoding parameters that you want to use before the output file name.  If you need to re-encode the audio, change `-acodec copy` as needed, e.g. to `-acodec libfdk_aac -vbr 3`.

Comment: Will this overlay the first 5 seconds of the video instead of putting it in front of it? (which would be fine). 
How can this be adjusted to also add an outro?
If I would like to add a waterwark to the rest of the video without the intro, is it possible to add an extra -filtercomplex to it or can I just play around with the inputs/outputs in filtercomplex to combine this?

Comment: With the `-itsoffset 5` it will put the intro in front and shift the video by 5 seconds, or remove that to overlay with no shifting.  To add an outro you can add a 3rd input like the 2nd (`-r` + `-loop` + `-i`), and add more filters to alpha-fade it in at the desired frame (e.g. length of the video × frame rate) and overlay it.  You can have as many filters as you like (e.g. fade in, watermark), separated by `;`, within a single `-filter_complex` argument.  See the documentation for complete details and some examples.

Comment: It seems that the general example of you is working.
I've still got two problems though.
One is: the intro has to overlay the complete videoframe. Any way on how to get the size of the frame of the video and this way match it?
Second: adding an outro. I can manage the extra filters with watermark and outro except that the outro has to end the video ofcourse. And I have no idea on how to manage that with overlaying the video with the outro and not the other way around.

Comment: You can use `ffprobe` to get the dimensions and duration first if you don't already know them.  Insert `scale=1280x720,` before the intro fade-out if you want to scale the intro to those dimensions.  If you want to fade to an outro I suggest overlaying the outro over the main video and fade it in, so that you won't need an alpha channel on your main video.  Use the duration to compute the time of the fade and its `-itsoffset`.  Or use the `concat` filter if you don't care about fading and just want a jump cut.

Comment: The output video are endless , how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

First create your video file from your image; you want 5 seconds per image? that means 0.2 image per second:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.png -r 0.2 intro.mkv
```

Then you can mux it together with your main movie using `ffmpeg` (or `mkvmerge` if they're all Matroska).

Comment: It indeed makes a 5 seconds mkv file.
But when I play it with VLC it immediatly stops playing.

I tried with a jpeg and png file but both give the same error.

Comment: You're right; this is probably a bad approach. http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images with a different approach suggests encoding to h.264 and forcing the output FPS as well, but for me even mplayer in that case won't play the whole five seconds.

Comment: ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i png.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 out.mp4

This seems to work though on the page you linked.
Now I can use that created output and combine it with the main video using concate.

But i'm confused how to put the made intro together with the concate function.

I tried ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i png.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 [intro].
I think this saves it into the parameter [intro].